# Does JavaScript support array/list comprehensions like Python?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an array from each individual integer from the string. In Python, I would do:

```py
string = '1234-5'
forbidden = '-'

print([int(i) for i in str(string) if i not in forbidden])
```

Does JavaScript have something similar?

Comment: No it does not. Although JavaScript does support [higher-ordered functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) and ES5 adds support for some basic map/filter support in Array.prototype (there is no direct flatmap, although that can be emulated map-concat). There are additional libraries like underscore which add to this set of 'primitives' that is all Python is doing under the list-comprehension syntax guise.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872615/are-es6-array-comprehensions-no-longer-valid

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Update:** Array comprehensions were removed from the standard. Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Array_comprehensions):

> The array comprehensions syntax is non-standard and removed starting with Firefox 58. For future-facing usages, consider using Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.filter, arrow functions, and spread syntax.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33873355/3583139) for an example with `Array.prototype.map`:

`let emails = people.map(({ email }) => email);`

**Original answer:**

Yes, JavaScript will support [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Array_comprehensions) in the upcoming EcmaScript version 7.

Here's an [example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=true&code=%20%20%20%20var%20str%20%3D%20%20%221234-5%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20ignore%20%3D%20%22-%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%5Bfor%20(i%20of%20str)%20if%20(!ignore.includes(i))%20i%5D)%3B).

```
var str =  "1234-5";
var ignore = "-";

console.log([for (i of str) if (!ignore.includes(i)) i]);
```

Comment: I believe the OP was asking about JavaScript code that they can actually run today, not at some indefinite time in the future.

Comment: Babel is great! Maybe you could expand your answer a bit and give an example of what the syntax would be, and how you can use Babel to use it in today's browsers.

Comment: Sure, see the update.  @user2864740: it is as it is, but array comprehensions will be a part of ES7 and with Babel one can use it now.

Comment: The MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions says at the top: "The array comprehensions is non-standard, and it's unlikely to be added to ECMAScript". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872615/are-es6-array-comprehensions-no-longer-valid seems to have more details

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles over this answer many years later, this does NOT work as proven by the "example" provided in the link above.

Comment: It's very sad that list comprehensions were never added to the language. They're very nice to use and easy to read.  Although, it's never too much effort to not use them.

Answer (score 27):

Given the question's Python code

```
print([int(i) for i in str(string) if i not in forbidden])
```

this is the most **direct** translation to JavaScript (ES2015):

```js
const string = '1234-5';
const forbidden = '-';

console.log([...string].filter(c => !forbidden.includes(c)).map(c => parseInt(c)));
// result: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Here is a comparison of the Python and JavaScript code elements being used:
(Python -> Javascript):

- print -> console.log
- unpacking string to list -> [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- list comprehension 'if' -> `Array.filter`
- list comprehension 'for' -> `Array.map`
- substr in str? -> string.includes

Answer (score 9):

Reading the code, I assume forbidden can have more than 1 character. I'm also assuming the output should be "12345"

```
var string = "12=34-5";

var forbidden = "=-";

console.log(string.split("").filter(function(str){
    return forbidden.indexOf(str) < 0;
}).join(""))
```

If the output is "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" on separate lines

```
var string = "12=34-5";

var forbidden = "=-";

string.split("").forEach(function(str){
    if (forbidden.indexOf(str) < 0) {
        console.log(str);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, but it's not hard to replicate.

```
var string = "1234-5";

var forbidden = "-";

string.split("").filter(function(str){
    if(forbidden.indexOf(str) < 0) {
        return str;
    }
}).forEach(function(letter) { console.log(letter);});
```

I guess more directly:

```
for(var i=0 ; i < str.length ; i++) {
    if(forbidden.indexOf(str) < 0) {
        console.log(str[i]);
    }
}
```

But there's no built in way to filter in your for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You could easily achieve this behavior using an application functor.

```
Array.prototype.ap = function(xs) {
  return this.reduce((acc, f) => acc.concat(xs.map(f)), []) 
}


const result = [x => x +1].ap([2])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Did you mean applicative functor? Can you give more context to your answer? It's quite intriguing.

Comment: while it seems interesting at a first sight, I cannot see any reason to use this instead of a plain `[2].map( x => x+1)`

Comment: My guess would be that it mimics the feel of the python equivalent

Comment: Compared to a pythonic list comprehension, this is quite ugly.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript no longer supports array comprehensions.

I too was looking for the JavaScript equivalent.  Mozilla Developer's [Network indicates that this functionality is no longer supported.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions)
The preferred syntax is referenced in the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 2):

For "completeness"-sake, here's a shorter regexp version.

```
var str =  "1234-5";
var ignore = "-=";

console.log(str.replace(new RegExp(ignore.split("").join("|")), "").split(""));
```

EDIT: To make sure that RegExp does not "choke" on special characters, `ignore` can be implemented as regexp literal, instead of a string:

```
var str =  "1234-5";
var ignore = /[\+=-]/;
console.log(str.replace(ignore, "").split(""));
```

Comment: `var ignore = "-+=";`

Comment: Dang, I really like your solution as well; it falls more in my type of coding

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't need list comprehensions because `map` and `filter` work better in the language compared to Python.

In Python:

```
[int(i) for i in '1234-5' if i != '-'] 
  
# is equivalent to the ugly
list(map(lambda _: int(_),filter(lambda _: _!='-','1234-5')))
```

Whereas in JavaScript, `map` and `filter` are `Array` methods, so:

```
[...'1234-5'].filter(_=> _!='-').map(_=> parseInt(_))
```

Comment: It is so frikking helpful to get this multilingual example. A Rosetta Stone of comprehensions, as it were. I am slightly less daunted by .filter() and .map() now.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at CoffeeScript.
CoffeeScript adds missing features to java-script and allows you to write cleaner, more readable code. https://coffeescript.org/#coffeescript-2

You write a .coffee file and the coffeScript-compiler compiles your coffee file into a JavaScript file. Because the translation into JavaScript happens by compiling, the script should not run any slower.

So your code would look like the following in coffee script:

```coffee
string = '1234-5'

forbidden = '-'

alert(JSON.stringify(+i for i in string when i isnt forbidden))
```

Honestly, this is even easier to read then the python counterpart. And it compiles quickly to the fallowing JavaScript:

```js
var forbidden, i, string;

string = '1234-5';

forbidden = '-';

alert(JSON.stringify((function() {
  var j, len, results;
  results = [];
  for (j = 0, len = string.length; j < len; j++) {
    i = string[j];
    if (i !== forbidden) {
      results.push(+i);
    }
  }
  return results;
})()));
```

You don’t even need to install anything. On their website you can play around with it, and it will show you the translated JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

It does have a poor mans version

```
const string = '1234-5'

const forbidden = '-'

print([int(i) for i in str(string) if i not in forbidden])
const result = string.split('').filter(char => char !== forbidden);
console.log(result)
```

In JS you can only iterate over single elements in array, so no extraction of multiple entries at a time like in Python.

For this particular case you should use a RegExp to filter the string though.

Comment: Please put the javascript and python code in two seperate code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the party, but as of 2024 I would do:

```js
console.log(string.split('').filter(i => !forbidden.includes(i)))
```