# What's the equivalent of a list comprehension like this one in ES2016 or greater?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, ecmascript-6, list-comprehension

Python 3.6:

`[f"Cat #{n}" for n in range(5)]`

gives

`['Cat #0', 'Cat #1', 'Cat #2', 'Cat #3', 'Cat #4']`

New to JavaScript, What's the equivalent in new EcmaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript support array/list comprehensions like Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353213/does-javascript-support-array-list-comprehensions-like-python)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Array comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) in JS was proposed for ES2016, but never made it to the final release. Firefox supported comprehensions for a time, but the support was dropped in later versions.

You can use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get something close to comprehension.

```js
const result = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, k) => `Cat #${k}`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's a clever use of `Array.from`! For some reason, Array.fill.map is faster in Chrome/Firefox, but this is *much* more readable.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't anything so lovely in Javascript. To the best of my knowledge, you need to create a new Array and use `.fill()` to make each element something other than `undefined`. Then you can use `.map` and return/work with the array index rather than the value. Something like this:

```js
console.log((new Array(5)).fill(0).map((x,i) => `Cat ${i}`))
```

You may find generators useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Generator_comprehensions

Answer (score 4):

Use the combination of [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

ES2015:

```
[...(function*(){for(let n=0;n<5;)yield'Cat #'+n++})()]
```

gives

```
["Cat #0", "Cat #1", "Cat #2", "Cat #3", "Cat #4"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
console.log( [...Array(5)].map((v, i) => `Cat #${i}`) )
```

If it has to work in IE too :

```js
console.log( Array.apply(0, Array(5)).map(function(v, i) { return 'Cat #' + i; }) )
```