# dynamically generate array using .forEach()

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

In python, you can do:

```
ints = [1, 2, 3]
str_ints = [str(my_int) for my_int in ints]
print(str_ints)
```

which outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

I want to do something similar using javascript using forEach,

```
let ints = [1, 2, 3]
str_ints = [ints.forEach(my_int => {return String(my_int)})]
console.log(str_ints)
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
Array ['1', '2', '3']
```

however, the output is

```
Array[undefined]
```

Is this sort of array creation not possible in javascript?

Comment: Why do you want to use `forEach` instead of functionality *designed* for the task you want?

Comment: Another way to simulate array comprehension in JS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310911/whats-the-equivalent-of-a-list-comprehension-like-this-one-in-es2016-or-greater/45311014#45311014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called mapping, and here's how you do it in JavaScript:

```js
var ints = [1, 2, 3];
var str_ints = ints.map((i) => String(i));
console.log(str_ints);
```

As suggested by @OriDrori, you can omit the arrow function:

```js
var ints = [1, 2, 3];
var str_ints = ints.map(String);
console.log(str_ints);
```