# Executing map function inside string concatenation

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to use the `map()` function while concatenating strings? If not, what is another approach?

I tried the following:

```
var data = [{ server: "one" }, { server: "two" }];
var output = "start " + data.map(function(i) { i.server}) + " end";
```

I wanted to use [Array Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353213/does-javascript-support-array-list-comprehensions-like-python) but I'm not running ES7, so I tried map with `=>`, but it's also not supported by whatever EcmaScript I'm running... So I modified it to be the above, but it still doesn't work with JSHint stating that it wants the `map()` to be executed independently.

Any approach is fine with me, as long as I can run it inline with the string concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to connect the new array generated by `map()` into one string.

```js
var data = [{ server: "one" }, { server: "two" }];
var output = "start " + data.map(function(i) { return i.server; }).join(' ') + " end";
console.log(output);
```

Comment: ES6 is easy as ``let output = `start ${data.map(i=>i.server).join` `} end`;``

Comment: It's certainly prettier that way. OP mentioned that he couldn't use arrow functions for some reason though.

Comment: The `${...}` is a placeholder in a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts. Most references I've seen regarding array comprehension and such goes back to that Mozilla page because it works with their engine. Are your solutions applicable to other browsers? Because I don't know what JS version I'm running, or how I can tell, but none of the comprehension or arrow functions work for me on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a return statement inside the map function and join the result as well, like this:

```
var data = [{ server: "one" }, { server: "two" }];
var output = "start " + data.map(function(i) { return i.server; }).join(" ") + " end";
```

Comment: Thanks, I just caught that it needed a return as well