# getting string from array in a shorter way

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

The below code works but is there a way to get the result in a shorter way, i.e. directly from the `map` function, avoiding `join` line, or maybe avoiding `arra` declaration in a separate line?

```js
let arra = $('.imga').toArray();

var arrb = arra.map(function(el) {
 return $(el).attr('data-id');
});

let str = arrb.join();

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd05fa00e7.jpg' data-id=442 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd09fa00e7.jpg' data-id=2 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd07fa00e7.jpg' data-id=54 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd03fa00e7.jpg' data-id=45 alt='img'>
```

Comment: You could use Array comprehension but it has been removed from the standard. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353213/does-javascript-support-array-list-comprehensions-like-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use chaining in your code if you want to reduce lines:

```
let str = $('.imga').toArray().map(function(el) {
    return $(el).attr('data-id');
}).join();
```

Comment: @MathKimRobin, as I can see result is set here as a variable. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can fasterize it by using directly the dom, like this el.dataset.id

Comment: Use `data()` to get data attributes in jQuery, not `attr()`. `return $(el).data('id');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tested the code before sharing and it works. Are you sure?

Comment: `attr()` will work, but it's not best practice as it uses `getAttribute()` instead of `datalist`, as `data()` does.

Comment: But why using the jquery way for just getting a property directly from dom ? It impacts performance and dataset property is standard and implemented on all browsers. Here for this part, jQuery provides nothing.

Comment: @MathKimRobin maybe the OP is using it everywhere else in the code and it's familiar. Questions usually have a wealth of context behind them. Perhaps you could have offered a non-jquery solution in your answer.

Comment: Done there https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277340/1717031 . Don't know why was downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following solution in a single line of code

```js
const string = [...document.querySelectorAll('.imga')].map(item => item.dataset.id).join(',');

console.log(string);
```

```html
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd05fa00e7.jpg' data-id=442 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd09fa00e7.jpg' data-id=2 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd07fa00e7.jpg' data-id=54 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd03fa00e7.jpg' data-id=45 alt='img'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting to an array use jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to grab the data attribute, then [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), and finally `join`. Because the code uses the callback parameters instead of `this` we can use an arrow function to stick it all on one line.

```js
const str = $('.imga').map((i, v) => v.dataset.id).get().join();

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd05fa00e7.jpg' data-id=442 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd09fa00e7.jpg' data-id=2 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd07fa00e7.jpg' data-id=54 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd03fa00e7.jpg' data-id=45 alt='img'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce.

```js
let arra = $('.imga').toArray();

var arrb = arra.reduce((op,el, index)=>{
   op += $(el).attr('data-id')
   if(index !== arra.length-1) op += ','
   return op;
},'');

console.log(arrb);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd05fa00e7.jpg' data-id=442 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd09fa00e7.jpg' data-id=2 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd07fa00e7.jpg' data-id=54 alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='images/5b0fd03fa00e7.jpg' data-id=45 alt='img'>
```

Comment: @qadenza it saves you from using extra join, what do you mean by shorter is it about number of lines only?

Comment: yes, but anyway your solution is creative and usefull. thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try to escape the `join` not necessary part. Like this

```
let arra = $('.imga').toArray(), 
    str = '' ;

var arrb = arra.forEach(function(el) {
    str += el.dataset.id;
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: there is no comma here, example pls

Comment: No comma ? I don't understand your point. Maybe just my english is not good but I don't understand the point about comma. With the code I provided, you have the same result as yours. But shorter and faster.

Comment: Oh OK, you didn't precise it in your question. So here it's a bit more complex. You have to add comma after concatenation except for the last one. Or each time and after remove the last char (it's obviously the useless last trailing comma). If you choose to add each time except for last, second param of forEach is the index of loop